# SQL Results of multiple case statements in one row

Tags: sql, case

I have a table that contains:

```
EXTDEP EXTCODE PRICE
200     10001   200
500     10001   25
600     10001   36
```

The result I want:

```
EXTCODE PRICE200 PRICE500 PRICE600
10001    200       25         36
```

The result I get:

```
EXTCODE PRICE200 PRICE500 PRICE600
10001    NULL      NULL        36
10001    NULL       25        NULL
10001    200       NULL       NULL
```

My code:

```
SELECT  
      [ExtCode]

      case when extdep = '200' then price1 end as '200', 
      case when extdep = '500' then price1 end AS '500', 
      case when extdep = '600' then price1 end AS '600'
```

Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this which applies an aggregate to the CASE statement:

```
SELECT  
      [ExtCode],

      MAX(case when extdep = '200' then price1 end) as '200', 
      MAX(case when extdep = '500' then price1 end) AS '500', 
      MAX(case when extdep = '600' then price1 end) AS '600'
FROM your_table
GROUP BY ExtCode
```

Comment: Should there be an `else 0` within each case so that you don't get the "Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation." warning?

Comment: No, the warning you get is from whatever you use as client, but not from MySQL itself. Ignore it. You don't want to change your data in an illegal way.

Comment: This is a good answer that is somewhat platform independent. Not all SQL languages can use PIVOT as described in some of these other answers.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the PIVOT function also like this:

```
SELECT [ExtCode],
     [1] AS '200',
     [2] AS'500',
     [3] AS'600'
FROM
 (
       Select [ExtCode], extdep, price1
       From your_table
  ) src
PIVOT
  ( 
      Max(price1)
      For extdep in ([1], [2], [3])
  ) piv
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative approach using PIVOT

```
SELECT *
FROM [table]
    PIVOT (MAX(PRICE) FOR EXTDEP IN ([200], [500], [600])) T
```

This generates the following output

```
EXTCODE     200         500         600
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
10001       200         25          36
```

Comment: Well this gives me the same output like my query